# ui-grid text aligns to right

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I am wrapping my grid with div that aligned to right, all my grid data also aligned to the right. 
How can I solve it? I must to wrap the grid this way.

```
<div align="right" style="margin-right: 135px">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-resize-columns class="grid"
            ui-grid-auto-resize style="margin-top: 15px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide images of what you see now and what you expect? It is difficult to tell what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` for `div` inside wrapper div.

```
<div align="right" style="margin-right: 135px">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-resize-columns class="grid"
            ui-grid-auto-resize style="margin-top: 15px; float:left;">Float Left text</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yx29uaob/1/)**

Comment: Hi, this makes my grid go back again to the left instead of to right.